# HTTP Rest Call using HttpClient in C# Get time out when byte array size becomes around 100 KB

Tags: c#, file, timeout, httpclient, webapi

I am calling to a rest api post method implement by me which has normal string parameters and one fileData byte array. I am just using application/json From Body technique to implement this service.

When i am calling to this api from C# code using HttpClient it is works fine for smaller files like 10-20 KBs. But when the file size is around 100-150 KBs PostAsync method is not getting anything untill the timeout happens. But when i call to same API from angular it is working fine for larger file sizes as well.

Below is my c# code block calling from client end. Please guide what is happening here.

```
Photo photo = new Photo
{
    CustomerMobile = row["CustomerMobile"].ToString(),
    PhotoCode = row["PhotoCode"].ToString(),
    PhotoSize = row["PhotoSize"].ToString(),
    TemplateId = int.Parse(row["TemplateId"].ToString()),
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(row["CreatedDate"].ToString()),
};

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["ExpiryDate"].ToString()))
    photo.ExpiryDate = DateTime.Parse(row["ExpiryDate"].ToString());
    
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(row["PhotoUrl"].ToString());

photo.FileData = data;
photo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(row["PhotoUrl"].ToString());

using var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.Configurations.APIBaseServerURL);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Settings.Configurations.Application, Settings.Configurations.ApplicationId);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Settings.Configurations.SessionID, sessionID);

response = client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(photo).ToString(),
                        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I see you are blocking on an async call with `.Result`. Maybe the larger file size causes the timing to be such that a deadlock is created. Can you not make your code async compatible?

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks for the comment. I just change the code as below but still it is blocking for timeout. ``` var t = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(url, httpContent));
                    t.Wait();
                    response = t.Result; ```

Comment: Yes, that is still a blocking call, not async at all. Is there any code in the call stack that is awaiting? Is this a .NET Core project?

Comment: @Crowcoder, Yes this is .NET Core 3.0 project. Can you suggest any code snippet to correct this deadlock happening ? I do not have much experience on anyc and awit.

Comment: Since .NET Core doesn't use a synchronization context there shouldn't be a deadlock. I guess the issue is something else and I have no idea. Do you have any exception handling and logging? Is the API under your control such that you can debug it or add logging?